# Android button background nine patch multiple images

Tags: android, button, nine-patch, android-drawable

I have three images that have gradient and are basically part of button left, center and right. Left and right have corners rounded.

Is their any way to combine all of them in layer-list? or any other approach so that i can make it as button background?

Comment: Your question doesn't quite make sense :). What exactly are you trying to achieve? Please elaborate.

Comment: Sure what I mean't was Three individual images to combine into one single background for the button

Comment: Is there any reason that you couldn't use a photo editor to combine these three images into a single nine-patch png? This would definitely be the easiest method. You could use a layered drawable and specify the same z-index (I think) and tweak the offset to achieve what you want, but this would be pretty difficult and it won't "stretch" correctly like a nine-patch png.

Comment: Actually I had that idea in mind but was curious to know if their is an easy way to do....i tired what is mentioned in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601357/how-do-i-make-a-drawable-from-multiple-images) but doesn't look neat

Comment: Oh, ok. I think that combining the three images into one png is going to be the easiest route. You could do what was described in that example. Then, however, you have to worry about telling the system how to stretch three different png's. Whereas when they are combined into one png you only have to worry about one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try having 3x [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) in a vertical oriented Liner Layout and set width to be 0.